# What's so special about Microsoft Office shortcuts?

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-office

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find the Target of an Advertised shortcut?](https://superuser.com/questions/263505/how-do-i-find-the-target-of-an-advertised-shortcut)

I want to start Microsoft Word 2010 with the `/m` switch. However when I open Word's toolbar shortcut I see that I can't edit the shortcut's `Target:` field:

[image]

In the image above the field is read only, and all of the Office application shortcuts are the same.

I know I can create a new shortcut to `WINWORD.EXE` to allow me to add this switch (and I did), but I'm curious as to what type of shortcut is being created by the Office installer, and why it doesn't let me change the target.

I'm running Office 2010 x64 on Windows 7 Ultimate x64.

Comment: It's some magical shortcut created by the installer. Use your own shortcut to WINWORD.EXE with /m if you want to run that instead.

Comment: @RandolphWest - I did, and said that I did, I just want to know what the *magic* is.

Comment: They're called 'advertised shortcuts'.  Some good links and stuff here: http://superuser.com/questions/263505/how-do-i-find-the-target-of-an-advertised-shortcut

Comment: Kev, I wasn't ignoring what you said, simply confirming it.